# optimising the re-arranging of a map into a vector of vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a map which contains integer values. i want to re-arange this map into a vector of vector such that, all the common elements are inside a one vector. so, i have implemented the following code.
but the problem is my map contains huge list of data in both direction.so, i am worring my method is slow as i am always erasing the elements of my map. So, i want to improve this method. do you think the erasing the element is the best way. if you know, give me some other efficient way. if you think my method can still improve please ammend my code. i have given a sample data how my data look likes to get you idea. 
i want this vector of vector to put a unique label for each common elements.
thank you in advance.

```
//populate my map from the upper part of my program

vector<int> list;
vector<vector<int> > listoflist;
map<int,vector<int> >::iterator it;
vector<int>::const_iterator any, is_in;

while (!my_map.empty()){
         it = my_map.begin();
         list.push_back(it->first);
         list.insert(list.end(), (it->second).begin(), (it->second).end());
         my_map.erase(it); // erase by iterator
         //go to next key and take its elements, if one is not inside add into list
         int newsize = list.size();
         for (int next=1; next<newsize; next++){          
              vector<int>& neb_to_next_element = my_map[list[next]];                
              for (any=neb_to_next_element.begin();
                     any!=neb_to_next_element.end(); any++){            
                   is_in = find (list.begin(), list.end(), *any);           
                   if(is_in==list.end()) list.push_back(*any);
              }
              //remove next now
              my_map.erase(list[next]);
              newsize = list.size();      
         }
         listoflist.push_back(list);
         list.clear();
}
```

here is part of my map

```
5 7 9
7 5 9 11
9 5 7 11
11 7 9
14 15 16 17
15 14 17
16 14 17 21
17 14 15 16 21
21 16 17
25 26
26 25
```

i want a vector of vector something like as follows

```
5 7 9 11
14 15 16 17 21
25 26
```

expecting your suggestions.

Comment: When asking a question, you should be quite clear with what the original problem is. In particular, what is the definition of *connected* in the first paragraph? What does the map contain (besides integers, what do they represent, what are the keys)? What do you want in the output vector of vectors?

Comment: @ David Rodríguez - dribeas: i have ammended the post bit. i want vector of vector to use all the common elementes seperately for other part. may be, i could use multy-map, but i dont know how i can add another key which is equal to index of my vec of vec in this case.

Comment: The problem is still not fully clear (too much code, but not enough explanation), but my understanding is that you want to build the sets of elements that appear together in any entry in the map, that is, if `a -> b, c` and `b -> d` then both sets should be merged into `a, b, c, d`, is that so?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I rolled back your edit, I hope that's O.K., because despite g_niro's invitation to amend his code, I don't think it's a good idea to make substantive changes to the code within the question itself. (After all, it then ceases to be the same question!)

Comment: @ruakh: The code was exactly equivalent, I only rearrange the definition of the variables to be closer to the usage, and thus avoid having to go back and forth. There was no *substantive* change to the code, as the compiler would generate the same code for both versions

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: yes, your thinking is write. i am sorry for my expressing faliers.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Well, if nothing else, you changed the number of calls to constructors and destructors. I doubt the compiler would optimize that away. (But I have to admit, when I performed the rollback, I didn't see that the loop had a `list.clear()` at the end, so it seemed like your change would affect the number of elements in `list` during the loop.)

Comment: i am not surely get what you said,but during the loop, some new elements will be added to the list. and when there are no more to add to the list, then it should be cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a vector of sets for the output:

```
typedef std::set<int>                   one_collection;
typedef std::vector<one_collection>     all_collections;
typedef std::map<int, std::vector<int>> source_data;

source_data     src;
all_collections dst;

while (!src.empty())
{
    dst.push_back(one_collection());
    one_collection & c = dst.back();

    source_data::const_iterator const it = src.begin();

    c.insert(it->first);
    c.insert(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());

    src.erase(it);

    for (one_collection::const_iterator jt = c.begin(), end = c.end(); jt != end; ++jt)
    {
        source_data::const_iterator const kt = src.find(*jt);

        if (kt == src.end()) continue;

        c.insert(kt->second.begin(), kt->second.end());
        src.erase(kt);
    }
}
```

Now each set in `dst` should contain one "connected collection".

(Pre-C++11 your iterators may have to be mutable-iterators, since `erase()` was broken previously.)

Comment: thanks, i am using dev c++. i hope, i could implement this code with the Dev.

Comment: other than vector of set, is this searching criteria is faster than my searching method? plz let me know. as i like follow this way

Comment: @g_niro: yes, it's faster, because `set` has faster lookup by value than `vector`. You can always copy the resulting set back into a vector, though, if that's preferable.

Comment: thanks for the codes. also, i want to know about your element searching strategy (find & continue) as it is bit different than my one. i guess your way is also faster. is that?

Answer (score 0):

> i am worring my method is slow as i am always erasing the elements of my map.

You should not be worried about this particular operation. Erasing elements from a map is not a very expensive operation (`O( log N )`, compare with erasing from a vector `O(N)`).

On the other hand, there are other operations that could be improved, like for example, building intermediate sets rather than looking up in the `list` vector whether an element still exists. Lookup in a set is `O(log N)`, while lookup in a vector is `O(N)`. This is theoretical complexity, as if the number of elements is rather small, the hidden constants might change the balance (in a set there is a dynamic allocation for each element inserted, while in a vector there will only be a few reallocations, which means that if N is small, the linear time of the vector lookup might be compensated by the lesser amount of dynamic allocations).